# Can I preview a react native bundle in web browser?

Tags: react-native

I would like to take the output of

`react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output index.ios.bundle --assets-dest ./`

And preview it in a frame in a web browser. Something that looks almost exactly like what [Facebook does here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html).

In the Facebook example you can see they have a live editor. I do not need that. I would, however, like to be able to preview images in my `assets/` folder, so in theory I would need to supply a `.bundle` file and a `.zip` of my assets.

This project (https://github.com/dabbott/react-native-web-player) seems the closest, but it does not appear to accept a bundle file, instead it wants the raw react native code or an array of "files" each of which contains raw react native code.

Does anyone know of any tools that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation uses [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io) to do exactly this with the examples.